# SVG Element is Vertically Centred and I don't want it to be

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to recreate the old DVD logo that would bounce around the tv screen using the SVG html element.

```html
<svg className='canvas'>
  <svg ref={this.image} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10%" viewBox="0 0 510 305" version="1.1">
    <g ref={this.g} id="g1" transform="matrix(6,0,0,6,48.16071,-418.59098)">
      <path id="path1" d="m 30.57323,69.90683 0,0.14991 0.14998,0.30006 0.15001,0.44999 0.14999,0.67505 0.37501,0.67497 0.22499,0.82497 0.22501,0.75005 0.29999,0.74996 0.22501,0.67505 0.14999,0.67497 0.15001,0.44998 0.6,1.57501 0.45,1.35003 0.29999,1.12496 0.375,0.90004 0.15001,0.74996 0.15,0.67505 0.075,0.37499 0.075,0.37498 0,0.29999 0.075,-0.075 0.075,-0.22499 0.15,-0.22507 0.22499,-0.37498 0.30001,-0.52498 0.52501,-0.59998 0.52498,-0.67497 0.67501,-0.90004 0.82499,-1.12495 0.97501,-1.20003 1.19999,-1.42502 0.30001,-0.29999 0.375,-0.44997 0.44999,-0.67505 0.67501,-0.67498 0.525,-0.74997 0.60001,-0.75004 0.67499,-0.74998 0.525,-0.59997 0.59999,-0.67505 0.37501,-0.37499 0.22499,-0.30006 0.075,-0.14991 17.24999,0 2.17501,0.14991 2.02499,0.22507 1.8,0.44998 1.72501,0.60005 1.49999,0.74997 1.35001,0.89997 1.12499,1.05003 0.975,1.05003 0.60002,1.19995 0.375,1.35002 0.075,1.35003 -0.22501,1.42494 -0.45,1.50001 -0.74999,1.35002 -0.97501,1.35003 -1.27499,1.19995 -1.425,1.12495 -1.57501,0.97504 -1.72499,0.89996 -1.875,0.82505 -2.02501,0.52505 -2.02498,0.44999 -2.10001,0.22498 -2.25,0.075 -11.55001,0 3.45001,-14.62502 8.175,0 -2.325,10.05005 1.8,0 1.425,-0.075 1.425,-0.15 1.425,-0.22499 1.19999,-0.37499 1.20002,-0.59997 1.12499,-0.60005 0.89999,-0.82498 0.75001,-0.82496 0.60001,-1.05004 0.44998,-1.20002 0.15001,-1.04995 -0.075,-0.97504 -0.29999,-0.89996 -0.6,-0.67505 -0.67501,-0.74998 -0.97499,-0.52497 -1.05,-0.44999 -1.20001,-0.30006 -1.34998,-0.14999 -1.57501,-0.075 -9.9,0 -18.75,21.30005 -7.425,-20.92506 0,-0.075 -0.075,-0.14999 0,-0.075 -0.15,-0.15 -0.075,0 -0.14999,0.15 0,0.075 0.075,0.075 0,0.15 0.075,0 0,0.075 0.22502,0.82504 0.14998,0.74997 0.075,0.90004 0.075,0.89996 0,0.75004 -0.075,0.74998 -0.075,0.52497 -0.45,1.50001 -0.825,1.35003 -0.975,1.35002 -1.20002,1.19988 -1.425,1.12495 -1.57501,0.97504 -1.79999,0.89996 -1.875,0.67505 -1.95001,0.67505 -2.09999,0.44999 -2.17501,0.22498 -2.09999,0.075 -11.625,0 3.525,-14.62502 8.175,0 -2.475,10.05005 1.95,0 1.425,-0.075 1.425,-0.15 1.275,-0.22499 1.35,-0.37499 1.19999,-0.59997 1.05002,-0.60005 0.89998,-0.82498 0.82501,-0.82496 0.52501,-1.05004 0.44998,-1.20002 0.15,-1.04995 -0.075,-0.97504 -0.375,-0.89996 -0.45,-0.67505 -0.74999,-0.74998 -0.9,-0.52497 -1.125,-0.44999 -1.2,-0.30006 -1.34999,-0.14999 -1.50001,-0.075 -10.12499,0 1.12499,-4.64996 31.12501,0" />
      <path id="path2" d="m 30.64821,103.58183 -1.5,0 -2.69998,-0.15007 -1.12501,-0.14992 -1.125,-0.22506 -0.9,-0.15 -0.75,-0.29999 -0.6,-0.29999 -0.30001,-0.29999 -0.14999,-0.29998 0.14999,-0.29999 0.30001,-0.22506 0.6,-0.37499 0.75,-0.22499 0.9,-0.225 1.125,-0.14999 1.12501,-0.15007 1.34998,-0.0749 1.35,-0.075 1.5,-0.075 1.5,0.075 1.42501,0.075 1.27499,0.0749 1.27501,0.15008 0.975,0.14999 0.97501,0.225 0.67499,0.22498 0.6,0.37499 0.29999,0.22507 0.15001,0.29999 -0.15001,0.29998 -0.29999,0.29999 -0.6,0.29999 -0.67499,0.29999 -0.97501,0.15 -0.975,0.22506 -1.27501,0.14992 -1.27499,0.0751 -1.42501,0.075 -1.5,0 z m 1.5,-7.65007 -3.67499,0 -3.6,0.0751 -3.375,0.15 -3.3,0.14992 -3.225,0.15007 -3.00001,0.29999 -2.925,0.22499 -2.7,0.29998 -2.475,0.30007 -2.325,0.37498 -2.09999,0.44993 -1.875,0.37497 -1.65001,0.375 -1.275,0.52498 -1.05,0.45005 -0.825,0.44999 -0.44999,0.52498 -0.15001,0.52505 0.15001,0.44998 0.44999,0.59998 0.825,0.44999 1.05,0.45005 1.275,0.52497 1.65001,0.37499 1.875,0.37499 2.09999,0.44998 2.325,0.37498 2.475,0.30006 2.7,0.29999 2.925,0.225 3.00001,0.29999 3.225,0.15006 3.3,0.15 3.375,0.14999 3.6,0 3.67499,0.075 3.67502,-0.075 3.52499,0 3.375,-0.14999 3.29999,-0.15 3.22501,-0.15006 2.99999,-0.29999 2.92501,-0.225 2.69999,-0.29999 2.55001,-0.30006 2.25,-0.37498 2.17499,-0.44998 1.8,-0.37499 1.65001,-0.37499 1.34999,-0.52497 0.975,-0.45005 0.82502,-0.44999 0.44998,-0.59998 0.15001,-0.44998 -0.15001,-0.52505 -0.44998,-0.52498 -0.82502,-0.44999 -0.975,-0.45005 -1.34999,-0.52498 -1.65001,-0.37499 -1.8,-0.37498 -2.17499,-0.44998 -2.25,-0.37499 -2.55001,-0.30006 -2.69999,-0.29999 -2.92501,-0.22499 -2.99999,-0.29999 -3.22501,-0.15007 -3.29999,-0.14991 -3.375,-0.15 -3.52499,-0.0751 -3.67502,0" />
      <path id="path3" d="m 71.59822,106.0568 -0.97501,0 -0.37499,2.92504 -0.45,0 0.375,-2.92504 -1.05001,0 0.075,-0.37506 2.475,0 -0.075,0.37506" />
      <path id="path4" d="m 75.04822,108.98184 -0.45,0 0,-2.55005 -1.35001,2.55005 -0.52499,-2.55005 -0.89999,2.55005 -0.375,0 1.12499,-3.3001 0.29999,0 0.525,2.17506 1.20001,-2.17506 0.45,0 0,3.3001" />
      <path id="path5" d="m 5.07322,117.53179 2.69999,-5.475 2.55001,0 -4.65,8.40004 -1.425,0 -4.57501,-8.40004 2.475,0 2.92501,5.475" />
      <path id="path6" d="m 16.02321,120.45683 2.25,0 0,-8.4 -2.25,0 0,8.4 z" />
      <path id="path7" d="m 28.39821,120.45683 -3.44998,0 0,-8.40004 3.44998,0 1.20001,0.075 1.12499,0.22499 1.05001,0.44998 0.82499,0.45005 0.67501,0.67498 0.525,0.67505 0.3,0.82496 0.075,0.82498 -0.075,0.90003 -0.3,0.74997 -0.525,0.75005 -0.75001,0.52497 -0.74999,0.59998 -1.05001,0.37506 -1.12499,0.22499 -1.20001,0.075 z m -0.67499,-6.97503 1.12499,0 0.9,0.225 0.67501,0.29999 0.59999,0.37499 0.45001,0.52505 0.225,0.59997 0.075,0.74998 -0.075,0.60005 -0.15001,0.52497 -0.22499,0.44999 -0.525,0.45005 -0.52501,0.29999 -0.67499,0.22491 -0.82501,0.15007 -1.04999,0.075 -0.37501,0 0,-5.55001 0.37501,0" />
      <path id="path8" d="m 42.72322,113.4818 0,1.875 3.675,0 0,1.42503 -3.675,0 0,2.24998 3.89999,0 0,1.42502 -6.225,0 0,-8.40004 6.225,0 0,1.42501 -3.89999,0" />
      <path id="path9" d="m 58.47322,120.45683 1.35,-0.075 1.125,-0.22499 1.04999,-0.37506 0.82501,-0.59998 0.75,-0.59997 0.525,-0.75004 0.29999,-0.74998 0.075,-0.82503 -0.075,-0.82498 -0.29999,-0.82496 -0.525,-0.60005 -0.75,-0.67498 -0.82501,-0.52505 -1.04999,-0.44998 -1.125,-0.22499 -1.35,-0.075 -1.20001,0.075 -1.12499,0.22499 -1.05001,0.44998 -0.82499,0.52505 -0.75001,0.67498 -0.52499,0.60005 -0.29999,0.82496 -0.075,0.82498 0.075,0.82503 0.29999,0.74998 0.52499,0.75004 0.75001,0.59997 0.82499,0.59998 1.05001,0.37506 1.12499,0.22499 1.20001,0.075 z m 0,-6.90003 0.89999,0.075 0.75,0.29999 0.67501,0.29999 0.525,0.37506 0.45,0.4499 0.22499,0.60005 0.075,0.52499 -0.075,0.60005 -0.22499,0.44997 -0.45,0.52499 -0.525,0.52505 -0.75,0.29999 -0.67501,0.22491 -0.89999,0.0751 -0.75,-0.0751 -0.82501,-0.22491 -0.59999,-0.29999 -0.525,-0.52505 -0.45,-0.52499 -0.22501,-0.44997 -0.075,-0.60005 0.075,-0.52499 0.22501,-0.60005 0.45,-0.4499 0.525,-0.37506 0.59999,-0.29999 0.82501,-0.29999 0.75,-0.075" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

This is what I've got so far. I have a parent SVG element which has some CSS styling to set its position to absolute and its width and height to 100%, so that it fills the whole window.

I then have the internal SVG element, which I've given a viewbox so that I can have the image be dynamically sized according to the size of the window.

This works but the SVG image ends up vertically centred in the window when x and y are set to 0, which is frustrating. I want the x=0 y=0 coordinate to be the top left of the window. If I am to remove the parent SVG element then the image successfully displays in the top left but I then can't use the coordinates to move it around the page, and if I don't specify a viewBox then I can use the coordinates and the origin is at the top left of the window but I have no control over the size of the image and it is rather larger than I would like.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using x and y to move your SVG around, you could use a translation. That would allow you to get rid of the outer SVG-element and have the inner one start positioned at the top left.

For example the CSS-rule `svg { transform: translate(10px, 10px); }` would move it 10px to the right and 10px down. Just set this as you would x and y otherwise.